# Get path to executable from command (as cmd does)

Tags: c#, .net, path, cmd, command-prompt

Given a command-line style path to a command such as `bin/server.exe` or `ping`, how can I get the full path to this executable (as cmd or `Process.Start` would resolve it)?

I tried `Path.GetFullPath`, but it always expands relative to the working directory. It expands `bin/server.exe` correctly, however given `ping` it returns `c:\users\matt\ping` (non-existent). I want `c:\Windows\system32\ping.exe`.

Edit: I would like the same behaviour as cmd. Some considerations:

1. When there is a local executable with the same name as one in the path, cmd prefers the local one
2. cmd can expand the command `server` to `server.bat` or `server.exe` (*adding the file extension*)

I also tried Windows' command-line tool called `where` . It does *almost* I want:

> Displays the location of files that match the search pattern. By default, the search is done along the current directory and in the paths specified by the PATH environment variable.

```
>where ping
C:\Windows\System32\PING.EXE
>where bin\server
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

---

(This question is hard to search around because of the two different meanings of the word 'path')

Comment: "two different meanings of the word 'path'" - actually, you probably want the other meaning: search through the PATH environment variable to find the first folder that contains ping.exe. It looks like you want the API method [SearchPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365527.aspx) - I'm not sure if this is available in .NET too, and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684392/is-there-a-managed-api-for-kernel32-searchpath) suggests it isn't.

Comment: Adding the file extension: that's easy too - you need to also look at the environment variable PATHEXT, semi-colon separated, and try combining those with the program name and PATH part.

Comment: related- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855956/check-if-an-executable-exists-in-the-windows-path

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242368/powershell-test-if-executable-in-path

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Considering PATHEXT too, stealing from Serj-Tm's answer (sorry! +1 to him):

```
public static string WhereSearch(string filename)
{
    var paths = new[]{ Environment.CurrentDirectory }
            .Concat(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH").Split(';'));
    var extensions = new[]{ String.Empty }
            .Concat(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATHEXT").Split(';')
                       .Where(e => e.StartsWith(".")));
    var combinations = paths.SelectMany(x => extensions,
            (path, extension) => Path.Combine(path, filename + extension));
    return combinations.FirstOrDefault(File.Exists);
}
```

Sorry the indentation's a bit all-over-the-place - I was trying to make it not scroll. I don't know if the StartsWith check is really necessary - I'm not sure how CMD copes with pathext entries without a leading dot.

Comment: Ah, I never knew about $PATHEXT

Comment: For the completeness, you should include the [following check](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/07/25/10189298.aspx):

    static string GetExecutablePathFromAppPaths(string exename)
    {
        const string appPaths = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths";

        var executableEntry = Path.Combine(appPaths, exename);

        using (var key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(executableEntry) ?? Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(executableEntry))
        {
            return (key != null) ? (string)key.GetValue(null) : null;
        }
    }

Comment: @ColonelPanic what are you talking about. this is regarding Windows. Windows uses %VAR% not $VAR this is not *nix

Comment: where is DarkGray's answer?

Comment: @barlop Looks like he's renamed himself in the past few years. It's the one I commented on, now by Serj-Tm.

Comment: cmd doesn't recognize extensions in PATHEXT that don't start with a dot, but one would have to be completely blind to put an extension in there without a dot. and a PATHEXT with an extension without a dot would be misconfigured, I think it's OK to assume a non corrupt PATHEXT and thus that every entry there starts with a dot.. If you want to take into account there not being a dot, it'd probably be better to exit with an error saying their PATHEXT variable is corrupt and they should fix it!

Comment: where you have this line  `var extensions = new[]{ String.Empty }.Concat(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATHEXT").Split(';') .Where(e => e.StartsWith(".")));`  Is there any reason for that new[]{String.Empty}.Concat,  i.e. wouldn't it be more compact to say `var extensions=Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATHEXT").Split(';').Where(e => e.StartsWith("."));`  ?

Comment: @barlop I think it's to catch the case where you include the extension in the search query, i.e. `WhereSearch("PING.EXE")` instead of just `WhereSearch("PING")`. But it was a few years ago!

Comment: @Rup is that a response to my "cmd doesn't recognize........." comment, or my "where you have this......." comment?

Comment: @barlop The second one: 'is there any reason...'. Honestly I didn't over-think this: I just came up with something that solved the problem in the question and worked in a few simple tests. I don't think I've looked this since then. You're right, there are probably edge-cases it misses or could handle better. Feel free to post a better version if you want, e.g. if you want to better deal with malformed PATHEXT.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110370/discussion-between-barlop-and-rup).

Answer (score 9):

```
public static string GetFullPath(string filename)    
{
 return new[]{Environment.CurrentDirectory}
  .Concat(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH").Split(';'))
  .Select(dir => Path.Combine(dir, filename))
  .FirstOrDefault(path => File.Exists(path));
}
```

Comment: Neat - you've got `fileName` in one place and `program` in the other though. (You can also write the last line just `.FirstOrDefault(File.Exists)` since `File.Exists` already accepts and returns the correct types, but I think it's clearer as-is.)

Answer (score 4):

If you're only interested in searching the current directory and the paths specified in the PATH environment variable, you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3856090/266143) snippet:

```
public static string GetFullPath(string fileName)
{
    if (File.Exists(fileName))
        return Path.GetFullPath(fileName);

    var values = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
    foreach (var path in values.Split(';'))
    {
        var fullPath = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
        if (File.Exists(fullPath))
            return fullPath;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to search the entire disk.

Windows can respond to things like, iexplore, ping, cmd, etc, because they are in the registry under this key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
   SOFTWARE
       Microsoft
           Windows
               CurrentVersion
                   App Paths
```

The only other way is to search the entire disk for the application.

EDIT: My understanding was, that you want to search for any random executable name, not the ones that are already known to Windows..

Answer (score 2):

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string fullPath = GetExactPathFromEnvironmentVar("ping.exe");
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fullPath))
            Console.WriteLine(fullPath);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Not found");
    }

    static string GetExactPathFromEnvironmentVar(string program)
    {
        var pathVar = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
        string[] folders = pathVar.Split(';');

        foreach (var folder in folders)
        {
            string path = Path.Combine(folder, program);
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                return path;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

HTH